# SQL Server - The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2017,
I want to stop/start a agent job of a remote server.

I executed the query

```
select * from openrowset('SQLOLEDB',
                          '192.168.56.101,2433';'monitor';'P@ssword',
                          'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=N''AG Sync Check'', @enabled=0')
```

and I got this result.

```
Msg 11520, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 9] The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting @retval OUTPUT' in procedure 'sp_is_sqlagent_starting' invokes an extended stored procedure.
```

I also tested with 'set fmtonly on/off' and nothing changed.

Please, anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From SQL Server 2012 onwards you need to describe the expected response structure when using OPENROWSETS to call procedures that on their turn call further procedures.

For instance, on SQL Server 2008 the below SELECT works to get the jobinfo that i use in a function of mine.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
'sqloledb'
,'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes'
,'set fmtonly off exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job')
```

However on SQL Server 2012 and higher this will return the same error as you're experiencing. To fix that we need to include the WITH RESULT SETS option to describe the returning SELECT statement. I.e.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
'sqloledb'
,'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes'
,'exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job WITH RESULT SETS
(
(job_id uniqueidentifier, originating_server nvarchar(30), name sysname, enabled tinyint, description nvarchar(512), start_step_id int, category sysname, owner sysname, notify_level_eventlog int,
notify_level_email int, notify_level_netsend int, notify_level_page int, notify_email_operator sysname, notify_netsend_operator sysname, notify_page_operator sysname, delete_level int,
date_created datetime, date_modified datetime, version_number int, last_run_date int, last_run_time int, last_run_outcome int, next_run_date int, next_run_time int, next_run_schedule_id int,
current_execution_status int, current_execution_step sysname, current_retry_attempt int, has_step int, has_schedule int, has_target int, type int)
)')
```

Coincidentally, the below method of specifying the results sets throws an error on SQL Server 2008. But since you've specified you're running on SQL Server 2017, i suspect if you describe the output using WITH RESULT SETS, the query should work fine.

Since you're running update job, this returns no values. But using WITH ROWSET NONE makes your SELECT FROM OPENROWSET invalid.

You should be able to to use

```
EXEC (@Command) AT <linkedServer>
```

If the linked server is configured to allow it and the server is actually registered as a linked server.

Comment: Thank you. I know this way. But I couldn't find the Result Sets of `sp_update_jobs`. Do you know the Result Sets of `sp_update_jobs`?

Comment: It doesn't. And you can't use ROWSET NONE, because then you're selecting no columns. Which throws another error on its own. Edited answer to include another possibility, using EXEC (@Command) AT <Linked Server>.

Comment: Awesome. I've solved this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've never seen this, thank you.

Comment: Also applies to OpenQuery.